# Does ffmpeg support streaming links

Tags: ffmpeg

Suppose i've ffmpeg installed on my server so as far as i know that the following command

```
<?PHP
exec("ffmpeg -i video.avi -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv -s 320x240 video.flv");
?>
```

so i wonder what if i can replace `video.avi` to streaming link like

```
$link = "http://www.my_channels.com:33811";
```

`$link` is streaming TV channel and i want to make it restreaming it as `.flv` so is it possible ! ~ Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$link` is a valid http steaming manifest, Yes. If `$link` is a page that contains a video, then no.

example:

Yes:

```
$link = "http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"
```

No:

```
$link = "http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbopall.html"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and i wonder if you can check out my question [using-ffmpeg-how-to-restream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428423/using-ffmpeg-how-to-restream)