# Using ffmpeg how to restream

Tags: ffmpeg

I do not know if it possible or not cause i'm very newbie to `ffmpeg`

suppose i've TV channel streaming link works with `vlc` plug-in to view it in firefox

```
$link = "http://www.my_site.com:13306"; // this is streaming tv channel link
```

Now by using `ffmpeg` i wonder if i can re-stream it and capture it as `.flv` so i can re-stream it using `jwplayer`

What i mean if the opposite of this command

```
ffmpeg -re -y -i "Video.mp4" -c:v libx264 -b:v 600k -r 25 -s 640x360 -t 40 -vf yadif -b:a 64k -ac 1 -ar 44100 -f flv "http://www.my_site.com:13306"
```

so can it be possible to re-stream using `ffmpeg`

~Thanks

Comment: suppose it is valid http steaming manifest input link

Comment: Instead of asking "is it possible" for several similar questions, you should rather ask *how* to do it and show what you've already tried. You're not getting really useful answers otherwise.

Comment: @slhck thank you for your comment but i really have no idea if it possible or not and my try is a kind of arbitrary try so i was wondering if it possible as if it was possible then i will do my best to find it how rather than searching for mirage :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to capture a (non protected) stream using ffmpeg. Once it is on your disk, you can do anything you want with it.

Depending on the content, rebroadcasting it could be illegal however.

Comment: Although accepted, I'm not sure this answers the question. Saving a file to disk requires the entire stream to be completed before it can be "re-streamed". It's possible this satisfied the poster's use-case however the answer by Ahmed Lotfy relating to streaming on-the-fly have significant advantages such as not requiring disk space and of course not needing to wait for the stream to finish before re-streaming - especially for a "TV Channel" which presumably never concludes a stream.

Comment: Ffmpeg can restream without touching the disk at all. Just set the output.

Answer (score 4):

you can re stream any http link to rtmp link using this

```
ffmpeg -i http://link.com:8001/1.ch -ar 44100 -vcodec libx264 -r 25 -b:v 500k -f flv rtmp://yourvpsDNS:1935/live/comedy;
```